# How can I build an .aar library with shrunk classes in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-proguard

I want to build an .aar library and proguard classes, but my library proguard file doesn't work, and I can see clear classes.

Here is my proguard file:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
         release {
         minifyEnabled true
         useProguard true
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules-my-lib.pro'
                 }
           }
    }
```

and app/build.gradle:

```
  android {
    buildTypes {
       release {
       minifyEnabled true
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can probably shrink and obfuscate the library itself, the usual practice is to leave `minifyEnabled` as `false` and provide the proguard configuration to the application, using `consumerProguardFiles` instead of `proguardFiles`.

This means that the minification is applied only once, on the whole application, using the merged configuration from the app's `proguardFiles` and the libraries `consumerProguardFiles`. This is usually more efficient because parts of the libraries not actually used by the application can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Android Studio Project and convert it to library [Follow this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html). Build and Execute the command Generate APK, .aar file will be created in release/debug folder.

Write the proguard rules as similar to APK, it will apply to .aar file also.

I hope this helps