# Remove Unused classes from library module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, proguard

[image]

If you see in the image `Viewpager2` module is getting added in the APK even though i am not using it anywhere in the code ,This apk contains code of one library which would be uploaded as `aar` in the jitpack .

How to remove unused resources like `Viewpager2` and many more from Library as we can't use **`shrinkResources true`** on a library.

This is increasing the APK size to a large amount .

When i use **`shrinkResources true`** on a `moduleName` it gives error as

```
Resource shrinker cannot be used for libraries.
```

Here's my build.gradle file .

```
 dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
        implementation project(path: ':moduleName')
    }
```

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I build an .aar library with shrunk classes in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046490/how-can-i-build-an-aar-library-with-shrunk-classes-in-android-studio)